# Virtual work method in pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

The problem illustrates two pulleys whose two ends are going downward with velocity $v$. The problem was about finding the velocity of the point $X$ i.e the point where the strings of the two pulleys meet.

As we can see,they solved the problem via virtual work method which is fine. But the statement of the method i learnt was *Work done by tension in a system of objects is $0$*. Here they used $Tu\cos 180^{\circ}$ *on a point of the string* instead of an object tied to a spring,which feels a bit uncomfortable to  me. If this method can be applied on points of the string,why didn't they use this approach for point $X$ instead of the block?I know that the point $X$ and the block will go with the same velocity,so they used that method on the block. But since they used $Tu\cos180^{\circ}$ earlier on two end points of the string,why aren't we taking $X$ into consideration in the equation?If we do that for $X$,then our equation comes $-2\times Tu\cos 180^{\circ}-2Tv\cos\theta+2Tv\cos\theta=0$ since tension on $X$ is downward which is $-2T\cos\theta$ and $X$ is going upward and tension on block is upward and velocity is also upward. But this begets an bizarre result which is $-2Tu=0$ or $T=0$. I know that for some reason, $X$ can't be taken into consideration in this problem but i am curious to know why.

I humbly request to point out the flaws and enlighten me with the proper concept. Also a few words on why and when using work done by tension on points of string instead of blocks is valid will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They used T1 on the block but then the moved on and put $T_1= T\cos(\Theta)+T\cos(\Theta)$ on X. I cant see why you have instead of T $T\cos(180°)=-T$.
Which T is positiv depends on the direction you choose to be positiv, but in anxcasr T1 and T have alternate sign.